# Click path to show/hide div

Tags: html, raphael

I'm trying to create a fairly straightforward interface with Raphael, whereby if you click on a given path you'll get a corresponding div to appear. Since I'm likely going to be using irregular shapes I'll be creating the shapes in Illustrator and then converting to paths using readysetraphael.com, but if there's a better way to do it I'm open to that too.

I'm basically looking to capture the functionality you see [here](http://codifydesign.com/chris/lynda/samples/course-0001/), but with raphael objects as the buttons.

http://jsfiddle.net/4xV7b/

Here's my current fiddle -- what I don't understand is what needs to happen during the mouseclick event to show/hide the corresponding divs.

```
el.click(function() {
   //mysterious voodoo magic goes here

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were using Raphael 2, you could use the `data` method to store arbitrary information with your elements -- as in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/kevindivdbyzero/NY6wJ/).

Essentially, when you're creating each path, you simply call

```
el.data( 'div_id', 'greenthing' );
```

Then, when that element is clicked, you can retrieve the indicated div from the element using

```
el.click( function()
    {
        var div_id = this.data( 'div_id' );
        // Display the div here.  Josemando's approach is perfectly cool and will work universally.
    } );
```

If you wanted to make sure that only one div at a time is displayed, you could do this (primitive but effective):

```
el.click( function()
    {
        rsr.forEach( function( subEl )
            {
                var divId = subEl.data('div_id' );
                if ( divId && document.getElementById( divId ) )
                    document.getElementById( divId ).style.display = 'none';
            } );
    } );
```

There are, of course, other ways to skin that cat.

You may also find that your path construction code would be more manageable if you put all of the shape-specific data into a structured object and then render each path in a loop.  The fiddle I've provided above demonstrates such a technique, which will pay off quickly once you have more than a handful of shapes.

Comment: This is great -- thanks so much! So, last question -- what would I need to do so that only one div displays at a time? Eg, when you click on a new shape, the previous div gets hidden and the div corresponding to the clicked shape appears?

Comment: That's a good question.  I'll update the answer to include a stab at that.  Did you have any issues updating to Raphael 2.0?  I noticed your fiddle was 1.5, which made me sad =(

Comment: Hah no, no problems with 1.5 -- the only reason I had it loaded was because it was loaded in the example fiddle from readysetraphael.com. Which is odd, since rsr generates stuff like the data attribute which is only available in 2.0. Many thanks again for your help.

Comment: Hi there -- I'm returning to this project after a hiatus. I still can't square the examples above with the jsfiddle version (http://jsfiddle.net/kevindivdbyzero/NY6wJ/) to actually make it display only one at a time. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pure javascript to show a div:

```
document.getElementById("redthing").style.display = "block";
```

If you want animations, you can try using jQuery, or even manually creating them with css

Comment: Great thanks -- that's a start! So how do I reference a particular attribute of the Raphael paths so that it displays the correct <div> based on the path clicked? For instance,

var buttonid = rsrGroups[i].//some attribute here?

...

document.getElementById("//attribute matching the variable above?").style.display = "block";

Comment: @user1866670 i updated your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4xV7b/4/) to make it work. You're referencing the div id using attr method and I believe Raphael doesn't allows it. I'm using a ugly workaround to make it work (using path's ids). I would go with Kevin's approach, it's cleanser :)